# Tabs in txt file vs terminal

Tags: python, file

I'm learning Python at the moment and I'm wondering why tabs look a little different in a txt file than when written to the terminal.

In particular, I've run this script

```
my_file = open('power.txt', 'w')
print( 'N \t\t2**N\t\t3**N' )
print( '---\t\t----\t\t----' )
my_file.write( 'N \t\t2**N\t\t3**N\n' )
my_file.write( '---\t\t----\t\t----\n' )

for N in range(11) :
    print( "{:d}\t\t{:d}\t\t{:d}".format(N, pow(2,N), pow(3,N)) )
    my_file.write( "{:d}\t\t{:d}\t\t{:d}\n".format(N, pow(2,N), pow(3,N)) )
my_file.close()
```

In it you can see that I'm writing the same thing to both the terminal and the power.txt file.  What I see in the terminal is

[image]

and what I see in the txt file is

[image]

As you can see the third column lines up much nicer in the terminal than the txt file.  I've got two questions:

1. As I'm writing the exact same data to both, why does the information display differently in the txt file?
2. If I wanted the columns in the txt file to line up like they do in the terminal (to improve readability), how could I alter my script to do so?

Comment: Looks like your text editor is configured to display tabs as 4 spaces (not 8, like the terminal).

Comment: You're right.  I just looked through the preferences and it was set to 4.  When I changed it to 8, I got identical output as the terminal.  So I guess I should just be aware of that and if I'm sending a data file to someone I'll let them know what to set their tabs to for the best display.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't rely on tabs, they're application/console dependent. Use `str.format` instead ([format specification](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html))

BTW `pow(2,N)` is a floating number. You want integral powers: `2**N`

Standalone example writing to standard output:

```
import sys

my_file = sys.stdout
header = "{:<10s}{:<10s}{:<10s}\n".format('N','2**N','3**N' )

my_file.write(header)

for N in range(11) :
    row =  "{:<10d}{:<10d}{:<10d}\n".format(N, 2**N, 3**N)
    my_file.write(row)
```

result:

```
N         2**N      3**N      
0         1         1         
1         2         3         
2         4         9         
3         8         27        
4         16        81        
5         32        243       
6         64        729       
7         128       2187      
8         256       6561      
9         512       19683     
10        1024      59049
```

(you could use legacy C-style format like `%20s` or `%-10s` but it's frowned upon now as deprecated, and the `format` interface is much much more powerful)

Comment: Awesome.  I'll accept in 4 minutes when it lets me. :)